# JavaScript not giving alert on invalid Confirm Password text

Tags: javascript, forms, passwords

For proper registration, user is required to enter password two times and password in both these textboxes should match.
However, on validating this using this code, JavaScript is not showing alert dialog.
Here `pswrd` and `pswrd1` are two textboxes of `password` type.

```
var message="";
var result=false;
if(pswrd.value!== pswrd1.value)
{
    message+="\nPasswords did not match";
    result=false;
}
if(!result)
{
    alert(message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var message="";
var result=false;
if(pswrd.value!== pswrd1.value)
{
    message = "Passwords did not match";
    result=false;
}
else {
    result = true;
}
if(!result)
{
    alert(message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
if(pswrd.value!== pswrd1.value)
{
  alert("Password does not matched!");
  return false;
}
```

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

if(pswrd.value **!==** pswrd1.value)

the text in bold above should be **!=** and not **!==**

**!==** is not an operator, use **==** for equality and **!=** for unequality